# Oracle - Compare Multiple Columns to Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, date-range

I have read access to a database. I want to check many (date) columns associated with multiple tables to see if the value of any of these columns falls outside a specified range.

For example, I might have TBL1.from_date, TBL2.from_date, TBL2.to_date, TBL3.birthdate all in the same date format. I want to check all columns to see if they fall between 1990 - 2025, without hard coding the date range in for each column. I am aware I can use the IN clause for a single value, but don't know how to specifically use it for comparison.

Current SQL query:

```
select TBL_A.acct_no
from   TBL_A, TBL1, TBL2, TBL3
where  TBL_A.acct_no = TBL1.acct_no and
       TBL1.acct_no  = TBL2.acct_no and
       TBL2.acct_no  = TBL3.acct_no and
       (
       TBL1.from_date < '01-JAN-1990' or 
       TBL1.from_date > '01-JAN-2025' or 
       TBL2.from_date < '01-JAN-1990' or 
       TBL2.from_date > '01-JAN-2025' or 
       TBL2.to_date   < '01-JAN-1990' or 
       TBL2.to_date   > '01-JAN-2025' or 
       TBL3.birthdate < '01-JAN-1990' or 
       TBL3.birthdate > '01-JAN-2025' or 
       );
```

Example SQL query of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
select TBL_A.acct_no
from   TBL_A, TBL1, TBL2, TBL3
where  TBL_A.acct_no = TBL1.acct_no and
       TBL1.acct_no  = TBL2.acct_no and
       TBL2.acct_no  = TBL3.acct_no and
       -- psudo-code
       (date range) not in (TBL1.from_date, TBL2.from_date, TBL2.to_date, TBL3.birthdate);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the conditions check if they fall between 1990 - 2025 or if they fall outside 1990 - 2025?

Comment: Outside - I updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: Are `NULL` values allowed or present in any of these columns? If not then @smrtskpr's answer could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the smallest column value with the lower boundary and the greatest column value with the upper boundary using `least()` and `greatest()` functions like this:

```
...and (
   least(    tbl1.from_date, tbl2.from_date, tbl2.to_date) < '01-JAN-1990' or
   greatest( tbl1.from_date, tbl2.from_date, tbl2.to_date) > '01-JAN-2025'
)
```

Comment: Assuming none of the columns contains a `NULL` value, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, null columns are common here

Comment: least(nvl(tbl1.from_date, '01-JAN-1990'),nvl(tbl2.from_date, '01-JAN-1990')) < '01-JAN-1990' or greatest(nvl(tbl1.from_date,'01-JAN-2025'), nvl(tbl2.from_date,'01-JAN-2025')... check if this works...